# If a set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is rectifiable, then $cA$ is rectifiable for all $c\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

**Recall:**

Definition. Let $S$ be a bounded set in $\mathbf{R}^{n} .$ If the constant function is integrable over $S$, we say that $S$ is rectifiable, and we define the $(n$ dimensional) volume of $S$ by the equation
$$
v(S)=\int_{S} 1
$$

Theorem. A subset $S$ of $\mathbf{R}^{n}$ is rectifiable if and only if $S$ is bounded and Bd $S$ has measure zero.

> For a set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R^n}$ and a scalar $c\in\mathbb{R}$ let $cA$ denote the set $\{cx:x\in A\}$. Prove the following:
>
> **Question** If a set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is rectifiable, then $cA$ is rectifiable for all $c\in\mathbb{R}$

I couldn't prove, may you help? Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Apply a change of variables to get an integral over $S$.

---

Using the theorem instead:

- Show that if $S$ is bounded, then $cS$ is bounded.
- Show that if $\operatorname{Bd}(S)$ has measure zero, then $\operatorname{Bd}(cS)$ has measure zero.

We show that the latter condition holds as follows: first, note that $\operatorname{Bd}(cS) = c\operatorname{Bd}(S)$.  Then, use the following.

**Claim:** If a set $K$ has measure zero, then so does the set $cK$.

**Proof:** The case where $c = 0$ is trivial.  If $c\neq 0$, proceed as follows. Suppose that $\mu(K) = 0$.  Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Let $(U_j)_{j=1}^\infty$ be a collection of open sets with $K \subset \bigcup_j U_j$ and $\sum_j \mu(U_j) = \epsilon/c$.  We note that $cU_j$ is open for each $j$, $cK \subset \bigcup_j (cU_j)$, and $\sum_j \mu(cU_j) = \sum_j c \cdot \epsilon/c = \epsilon$.

We conclude that $cK$ is indeed of measure $0$.

Comment: We have not learned change variables theorem yet. We can only use above definiton and above theorem

Comment: All right, updated accordingly.  Which of those two steps are you having trouble with?

Comment: Ahh thanks but I know that I need to show these but I couldn't show ''Show that if $\mathrm{Bd}(S)$ has measure zero, then $\mathrm{Bd}(c S)$ has measure zero.,'' may you add this here, please?

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: Thanks :) $\mu(K)$ means volume of $K$, right? and why did you say $\mu(K)=0$, may you explain? I think: Since $K$ is rectifiable, then $\mu(K)=0$ :)

Comment: By the way, the phrase "may you $X$" is a bit strange; the usual phrasing is "can you $X$".  [Here's an interesting post](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/118576/46438) about the issue from another SE site.

Comment: $\mu$ here refers to "measure".  Since the term is used in the theorem, I assumed that you are familiar with it.  It is basically volume, as you said.  The point of the claim is to apply it to $K = \operatorname{Bd}(S)$.

Comment: I know ''may'' is more courteus than ''can'', hence I used ''may'' I will see thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for answer and comments

Comment: How did you get this equality ''  $\sum_j \mu(cU_j) = \sum_j c \cdot \epsilon/c$  ''? I think $\mu(cU_j)=|c|^n \mu(U_j)$ for any $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: And you got $\sum_j \mu(cU_j)=\varepsilon$ but we need to show $\sum_j \mu(cU_j)\leq\varepsilon$ as definition of have measure zero, right? Could you explain that, please?